# Set Favorite: Is the following Use Case Diagram correct?

Tags: uml, use-case

Case(Detailed): User select some files in android applicaiton and send SOAP request to WebService to set the selected files as Favorite.

Case(With few words): User want to set some files as favorites

Sequence Diagram is:
`User-->FileBrowser-->WebService-->DbManager-->Database`

So, is the below diagram correct or i am missing something?

[image: Use Case Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram looks fine. However, I noticed from your other question that you are now mixing business and technical aspects. If you want to do a use case synthesis for the business (which is the most common application of that) you must not start mixing technical aspects. Having said this, Login is not a business use case. A use case describes in short terms the added value which an actor receives when applying it. On a business level, a login is just a constraint since it does not add any value.

As an advice:

- Start with use cases on a pure business perspective.
- Think what actually is added value.
- Which are the stakeholders?
- What are their requirements?
- Which requirements can be synthesized to use cases?

Only after that start a technical design. In that you may use use cases on a technical level where you may describe a Login use case as part of an authentication sub-system.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not include some kind of system, whereby user and server is outside of it? My teachers always commented on involving the system. 
List all the users outside the system. The use case serves as an answer to:"What will the system do?". Is the database used by external users/systems? In that case it's better to represent it as a seperate actor.

Perhaps an idea to write a full use case before making a use casediagram.

Comment: Yes, showing the system under consideration (SUC) as boundary is a plus. From a closer look the use cases are on the border of the SUC since they represent the communication between actor and SUC. But it's also quite common to just place the UCs inside the SUC boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are not according to UML:

1. The include dependency should have an open arrowhead pointing to 'selct file'.
2. The word include must be surrounded by «guillemets»

Recommendations:

1. Use a consistent naming convention for the use cases. It is common to use imperative style, with at least one verb and one noun e.g. "Select file" and "Choose favorite files".
2. Draw a system boundary (rectangle) around the use cases, leaving the actors outside of the boundary. Enter a descriptive name inside the boundary, e.g. "Android app".